# Disabling scrolling on UITableView prevents didSelectRowAtIndexPath from being called

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I have a UITableView that I want to remain stationary. But when I set self.tableView.scrollEnabled = NO, the first time you tap a cell, didSelectRowAtIndexPath is not called. The second time it is called, however. What could I do to prevent this?
Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't accidentally implementing `didDeselectCellAtIndexPath`?

Comment: No, I'm not. I found a hacky workaround, though. If I leave scrolling enabled, but disable bounce it works.